# ADAL v3.x with UWP project in Xamarin forms app

Tags: authentication, xamarin, adal

I’m trying to use the latest version of ADAL (v3.13.5) in a Xamarin Forms app, using the guidance and sample published here:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/07/22/using-adal-3-x-with-xamarin-forms/

I’m noticing, though, that I can’t install ADAL v3.x in the UWP project of the Xamarin Forms solution. I’ve pasted the errors I’m getting in the output below.

I’ve also noticed the same issue when I try to install ADAL v3.x in a simple UWP solution as well. It looks like v2.28.2 is the latest version of ADAL that I can install in any UWP project. Is there a way to work around this so that I can implement the same version of ADAL, and therefore the same authentication implementation, across all three projects in a Xamarin Forms app? For now, is v2.x the only available option for ADAL in UWP?

Detected package downgrade: System.Text.RegularExpressions from 4.1.0 to 4.0.12 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.5) -> System.Xml.ReaderWriter (>= 4.0.11) -> System.Text.RegularExpressions (>= 4.1.0) 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.5) -> System.Text.RegularExpressions (>= 4.0.12)
Detected package downgrade: System.Text.RegularExpressions from 4.1.0 to 4.0.12 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.5) -> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json (>= 4.0.2) -> System.Private.DataContractSerialization (>= 4.1.1) -> System.Text.RegularExpressions (>= 4.1.0) 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (>= 3.13.5) -> System.Text.RegularExpressions (>= 4.0.12)
Version conflict detected for System.Collections. 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 5.0.0) -> System.Net.Sockets (>= 4.0.0) -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets (>= 4.1.0) -> System.Collections (>= 4.0.11) 
 App1.UWP (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (>= 5.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-arm (>= 1.0.0) -> System.Collections (= 4.0.10).
Package restore failed for 'App1.UWP'.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App1.UWP'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this will help, but check the profile that your Xamarin project targets. ADAL 3.x removed support for Windows Phone 8.1. If your project targets a profile that includes WP, you won't be able to install ADAL.

Comment: Thanks. In my project, I've already followed these instructions: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-connect-sample/wiki/Set-up-a-Xamarin-Forms-project-to-use-the-MSAL-.NET-SDK. So I've already removed that target. The problem is that the UWP template loads packages that have dependencies that conflict with ADAL v3.x dependencies, so any attempt to install ADAL v3.x fails.

Comment: Interesting, I'd recommend filing an issue on the library.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/547

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.13.7

Issue was with the way nuget dependencies were described